# Structuring mixed regression-classification neural nets

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, keras

I'm working on a key points detection problem where the input is an image and the output is a set of key points. Now, keypoints may or may not be visible. So for a given keypoint (let's say the right shoulder), the output could be [presence, x_coordinate, y_coordinate] either (1) [1, 200, 300] for a keypoint that's present and located at X=200 and Y=300 or (2) [0,0,0] for a keypoint that is not present. The first value (1 or 0) is for presence.

**How do I structure the neural net output layer to handle these types of problems?**